# Move label above bar

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm using HighCharts to display a list of budgets, but am limited for horizontal space.

At the moment, I have this:

[image]

But what I would like to have, is the label being moved INTO the graph, written above each bar. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable categories on xAxis, then simply use dataLabels instead:

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,   
                format: '{key}',
                inside: true,
                align: 'left',
                crop: false,
                overflow: 'none',
                y: -20
            }
        }
    }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zf7te5ef/3/

Comment: Can you see why my labels are not displaying? I tried your example using my code:http://jsfiddle.net/umpvrq5n/

Comment: You have set `plotOptions` twice in one object. Anyway, example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/umpvrq5n/4/